# Issue with generics, interfaces, and casting

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface, user-controls

I recently added an interface to some custom user controls I have implemented. The interface is pretty basic. It has one method that supports chaining:

```
Public Interface IMyInterface(Of T As WebControl)
    Function DoSomething() As T
End Interface
```

The implementations are also pretty basic:

```
Public Class MyCustomControl
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl)

Public Function DoSomething() As MyCustomControl _
    Implements IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl).DoSomething
    ' do stuff

    Return Me
End Class
```

Everything works fine up to this point. The issues arise when I attempt to loop over a collection of controls that all implement the `IMyInterface` interface, like so:

```
Dim myList = New List(Of IMyInterface(Of WebControl))

myList.Add(someCustomControl)

myList.ForEach(Sub(i) i.DoSomething())
```

`someCustomControl` is a `MyCustomControl` which implements `IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl)` instead of `IMyInterface(Of WebControl)`.

I am getting this error on the second line (where I try to add `someCustomControl`):

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'MyCustomControl' to 'IMyInterface(Of WebControl)'.

Is there any way to get around this error? I am close to having it working but I do not know enough about generics to get beyond this point.

Comment: While you try to declare myList like `Dim myList = New List(Of IMyInterface(Of WebControl))` instead try `Dim myList = New List(Of Object)` or something like that.

Comment: @Vishal I think without having the `IMyInterface` type you would unable to call `DoSomething()` on the objects in the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: sorry, I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Covariance is a language feature that was introduced in VS 2010, and solves your problem. You need to define your generic such that the type `T` has the `Out` keyword in front of it:

```vb
Public Interface IMyInterface(Of Out T As WebControl)
    Function DoSomething() As T
End Interface
```

When you use the `Out` keyword, you are using covariance. It allows generics of a more derived type to be used in place of a generic with the base type. So in your case it will allow a `IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl))` object in places where the code would normally expect `IMyInterface(Of WebControl))`, such as your `for` loop.

Note that covariance has a restriction. The covariant type `T` can only be used as a function return value, and not as a parameter into a function (or sub). For example, if the `DoSomething` signature in `IMyInterface` looked like this the compiler would complain:

```
' Here the type T is used as an input param - compiler error
Sub DoSomething(ByVal sampleArg As T)
```

Given your chaining scenario, I don't think the above restriction is a problem.

More Info at MSDN:

- [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Creating Variant Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your function `DoSomething` does, but I try assigning the instance's CssClass in there for testing purpose.

Declare the interface as follows:

```
Public Interface IMyInterface(Of Out T As WebControl)
    Function DoSomething() As T
End Interface
```

Notice the **`Out T`** parameter.

Create 2 controls that implement the interface:

```
Public Class MyCustomControl1
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl1)

    Public Function DoSomething() As MyCustomControl1 Implements IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl1).DoSomething
        ' do stuff
        Me.CssClass = "XXX"
        Return Me
    End Function

End Class

Public Class MyCustomControl2
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl2)

    Public Function DoSomething() As MyCustomControl2 Implements IMyInterface(Of MyCustomControl2).DoSomething
        ' do stuff
        Me.CssClass = "YYY"
        Return Me
    End Function

End Class
```

On a test page's PageLoad event:

```
Dim someCustomControl As New MyCustomControl1
Dim someCustomControl2 As New MyCustomControl2

Dim myList = New List(Of IMyInterface(Of WebControl))

myList.Add(someCustomControl)
myList.Add(someCustomControl2)

myList.ForEach(Sub(i) Literal1.Text &= i.DoSomething.CssClass & "<br />")
```

The result is, the `CssClass` property of both someCustomControl & someCustomControl2 are set to the respective values.

This shows that the interface function `DoSomething` was successfully called and the instance changed.

Comment: `Out` is what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast the object before adding it:

```
myList.Add(CType(someCustomControl, IMyInterface(Of WebControl)))
```

You may also want to concider making the interface not generic and your "DoWork" method return type as the interface itself.

```
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Function DoSomething() As IMyInterface
End Interface
```

When you have to specify the type in the interface definition it kind of takes away from the power of interfaces (not having to know about the implementation).

Comment: I'd like to be able to get it working without breaking the chaining functionality

Comment: If the interface returning itself does not satisfy your chaining functionality then the interface should be redesigned, or don't use interfaces. Alternatively you could write a base class of `WebControl` which does the same.